# Calculating Probability of Purchase Decision

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find the probability that someone will return a product they purchased given a certain amount of days that have passed since their initial purchase.

For example, assuming a normal distribution and that I have 60 samples, with a S.D. = 34 days and Mean = 55 days, how can I determine the probability that someone will return a product given that they have kept it for 20 days?

How would I formulate this problem? I can calculate the Z-Score but I'm not sure where to go from there - is there some sort of model or distribution that I should look into?

Comment: You might have luck if you look into survival analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What [@SeanEaster says](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264846/calculating-probability-of-purchase-decision#comment528424_264846). *What* would you model with the normal distribution? If you are modeling the number of days before the product is returned, then what do you do with products that are *not* returned? This kind of model won't be helpful.

Look into survival analysis.